# EWS Managed API 2.0 sending mails without signature

Tags: office365, ews-managed-api, exchange-server-2013

I have some code that sends e-mails via EWS Managed API 2. 
I'm having an issue though with sending e-mails without the sending user's signature being attached to the email automatically.

If even possible, I would like to be able to send e-mails via different user accounts without each user's personal signature being added at the bottom of the mail body.

Is there a way to do this?

Also, when I provide an email address and a password (in WebCredential) to the ExchangeService it appears that regardless of what I try to set as EmailMessage.From and EmailMessage.Sender it just ignores these values and puts in the values that the server knows.

For example, if I have an account like this:

Name: *Firstname Lastname*

Address: *firstnamelastname@companydomain.com*

And I want to send e-mails using this account, but I don't want *Firstname Lastname* to appear as the sender of the email but maybe instead *Support* or *Assistance*.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Sending mails without signature**

The signature is part of the email body.

You could look in the email body for some common signature phrases, like 'Best Regards', using `Regex.Match`.

You may have to add multiple signature phrase variations. This obviously is not fool proof.

```
var signitureTerm = "Best Regards";
var match = Regex.Match(item.Body.Text, signitureTerm);
if (match.Success)
{
    //Remove signature from email body
}
```

**Custom Email Sender**

What your looking for is not possible in EWS.

When you send a message via EWS, it's submitted via the Exchange store, so the Sender address will be resolved back to the default Reply address for whatever account your trying to send as.

Comment: @Aidal if this answered your questions then please mark as answer.